# Как спарсить картинку с сайта на Java

Tags: java, парсер

хочу спарсить картинку в приложение с [сайта](https://yandex.ru/pogoda/moscow), как это можно сделать? Делаю небольшое приложение, нужно достать фон, на котором написана основная погода.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://yandex.ru/image.jpg"));
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
```

Comment: А что мешает в вашем примере кода сразу скачать картинку по ссылке в файл, для чего `ImageIO`?

Comment: Чтобы меньше было кода

Comment: А не нужно использовать никакой html код, для обозначения конкретной картинки (мне нужна та, на которой основная погода написана)?

Comment: Боюсь там и не картинка вовсе, нужно использовать другой подход.

Comment: @lampa а что нужно сделать?